Multiple optimal solutions in Simplex method when solving Linear Programming
What is the Simplex tableau would be if there are multiple optimal solutions in solving Linear Programming.
I think there must be a test number $r_j$ for a nonbasic variable $x_j$ equals 0. And at least one element $a_{ij}$ in the column of $x_j$ is positive. Then pivot according to the $a_{ij}$ will reach another basic optimal solution. Is it right?
Another question is, is it possible that there are multiple optimal solutions, but all elements in the column of $x_j$ is non-positive? If it is possible, then how can we pivot to another basic optimal solution. If it is impossible, how can we prove the impossibility.
The reverse question is. If there is a test number $r_j$ for a nonbasic variable $x_j$ equals 0, does it always lead to multiple optimal solutions?

For your first question, yes that interpretation is right, as when the reduced cost, say $c^\pi_{x_i}=0$, for any NBV, what we are effectively saying is we can pivot that variable in without change in the objective function as the column satisfies the row-echelon form of the Simplex Method requires of BV.
For your second question, yes that can happen for an unbounded problem, and you cannot pivot towards the other optimal extreme direction because it does not exist. For example, given the following program
$$
\begin{array}{ll}
\max & z= y\\
s.t & x+y\ge5
\end{array}
$$
has an optimal solution at the extreme point $(x,y)=(0,5)$, and the whole line to the right of it has multiple optimal solutions for the problem where the only difference is the $x$ values. Thus, in the Simplex Method, upon reaching that single extreme point, will have the reduced cost of $x$ be 0 with negative column entries due to it being unbounded.

Thus, to answer the reverse question, it does always lead to multiple optimal solutions.
